# How can I draw a custom country map via GeoDataFrame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have an issue about drawing my country via GeoDataFrame in Python.

After the essential process has been done, I got a dataframe shown below in my country.

The code snippet throws an error about size of dataframe.

How can I fix it?

Here is my dataframe

```
    index   Longitude   Latitude    geometry
0   0   27.000  41.000  POINT (27.00000 41.00000)
1   1   27.400  37.800  POINT (27.40000 37.80000)
2   2   27.300  37.850  POINT (27.30000 37.85000)
3   3   28.900  40.500  POINT (28.90000 40.50000)
4   4   36.100  36.100  POINT (36.10000 36.10000)
... ... ... ... ...
317 317 27.414  36.929  POINT (27.41400 36.92900)
318 318 38.514  37.596  POINT (38.51400 37.59600)
319 319 29.697  37.948  POINT (29.69700 37.94800)
320 320 28.173  40.890  POINT (28.17300 40.89000)
321 321 39.081  38.390  POINT (39.08100 38.39000)
```

Here is my code snippet

```
df_point_TURKEY = df_point[df_point["Country"] == "TURKEY"]

df_point_TURKEY = df_point_TURKEY.drop("Country", axis=1)

df_point_TURKEY.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df_point_TURKEY["index"] = np.arange(0,len(df_point_TURKEY))

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df_point_TURKEY['Longitude'], df_point_TURKEY['Latitude'])]
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df_point, geometry=geometry)   

#this is a simple map that goes with geopandas
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

gdf.plot(ax=world[world["name"] == "Turkey"].plot(figsize=(16, 8)), 
         marker='o', 
         color='red', 
         markersize=15
        );

plt.title('Earthquakes occurred from 2100 BC in Turkey',fontsize = 25)
plt.savefig('images/image12.png')
plt.show()
```

The error : `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to change code

Replace

```
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df_point, geometry=geometry)
```

with

```
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df_point_TURKEY, geometry=geometry)
```